# Is there an easy way to go about creating a "tab-sensitive" button in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, wpf-controls

Suppose I have 2 tabs with parameters to be set and two `Button`s under them, one serves to Ok the procedure and do the math, the other clears the values entered by the user to their defaults.

What I'd like to do is to make the Clear `Button` sensitive to whatever tab is currently active. So if I'm in Tab 1 and press "Clear", only the Tab 1 values are back to their defaults. Is there an easy way to do this?

I also realize having a clear `Button` on each tab might be easier to do, but I don't think it'd look as good. Though I might consider this or just resetting all the values if there is no clean alternative.

Comment: What kind of architecture are you using? The answer is a lot different if you're using MVVM and commands than if you're using something like Click handlers in code behind to do the clearing. Are the tab items bound to individual data objects, a collection, or not bound at all?

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure to be honest. I'm just inserting stuff with XAML at the moment, so I guess they're not bound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply check which tab is currently selected from the code-behind?

I've uploaded a working example **[here](http://cid-092d535af13fe697.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/WpfApplication2.zip)**.

But this should give you an overall idea

```
    private void bOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0: Tab0_OK(); break;
            case 1: Tab1_OK(); break;
        }
    }

    private void bClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0: Tab0_Clear(); break;
            case 1: Tab1_Clear(); break;
        }
    }
```

Regards,
Mihir Gokani

Answer (score 0):

You can check which tab is currently selected by using the following command.

If DirectCast(DirectCast(YourtabCtrl, System.Windows.Forms.TabControl).SelectedTab,Sytemtem.Windows.Forms.TabPage).Name="Tab1" then
 'Clear controls
Else
 'Clear Controls
End if

Hope this is going to help.

Thanks,
Jagdev josan